# tag colors incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, style

the tag color for english site seem incorrect, the dark grey color is the background while the yellow colour is the foreground. This is contradictory to other sites which have the darker colours as the foreground and lighter colours as the background.

---

Current foreground: [image] (#F4ECE3)

Current Background: [image] (#5E5E5E)

---

In comparison to Stackoverflow:

Foreground: [image]

Background: [image]

---

As you can see the darker colour is background on english, and vice versa on SO.

On the actual english site's CSS `color:#5E5E5E` and `background-color:#F4ECE3` (IE the opposite of the API)

Also may I suggest that on the next [semi-]major API update the `tag_foreground_color` be changed to `tag_text_color`. Its more descriptive and, unlike SO where the tag border is the same color to the text, SE sites text color is different to the border color

Comment: This belongs on meta.english.stackexchange.com

Comment: No I'm saying the API gives te colours mixed up. The background and foreground tag colors for English site need to be swapped in the API results

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you were referring to a result from an API query. You're right, though, it is backwards (but I'd call that pink rather than yellow).

Comment: The english tag is yellow. I've put the colors in the question:

Comment: Sorry, pink would be #F4E3EC, but I'd still call that a very pale orange and not at all a yellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colors have been flipped, apparently a data entry error as part of the new design push.

Comment: Yes my point exactly, can they be unflipped?

Comment: @Jonathan - ah, sorry I wasn't clear.  This has been fixed on dev, and will go out with the next build.

Comment: cool :) good to see you back btw.